# how to get particular words from file and how to update those in a table

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, unix

I have a file:

```
$ cat dd.txt
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            File: log-bin.00005
        Position: 120614936
    Binlog_Do_DB:
Binlog_Ignore_DB:
```

I want only these values from above file `log-bin.000055, 120614936`

Now I want to update `file,position` in my slave table.

```
update db.position set binlog_file='log-bin.000055',position='120614936' where master_host='master.tb.com';
```

How do I write a simple script for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GNU Grep` and [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```bsh
$ grep -Po "(?<=File: )[^ ]+|(?<=Position: )[0-9]+" dd.txt
log-bin.00005
120614936

# Store file in variable 
$ file=$(grep -Po "(?<=File: )[^ ]+" dd.txt)

# Store position in variable
$ pos=$(grep -Po "(?<=Position: )[0-9]+" dd.txt)

# Generate query using variable and store in variable
$ query="update db.position set binlog_file='"$file"',position='$pos' where master_host='master.tb.com';"

$ echo $query    

update db.position set binlog_file='log-bin.00005',position='120614936' where master_host='master.tb.com';

# Pipe query to mysql
$ echo $query | mysql -u user -ppassword
```

As a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file=$(grep -Po "(?<=File: )[^ ]+" dd.txt)
pos=$(grep -Po "(?<=Position: )[0-9]+" dd.txt)

$ query="update db.position set binlog_file='"$file"',position='$pos' where master_host='master.tb.com';"
$ echo $query | mysql -u user -ppassword
```

Comment: thanks @@sudo_O i want one more help i have a file like this                                                        [roome@server ~]# cat file
-- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000025', MASTER_LOG_POS=107;
now i want only mysql-bin.000025,107 from the file how can i do this

Comment: Like this `grep -Po "(?<==')[^']+" file`

Answer (score 1):

To get the specified data you can do this:

```
cat dd.txt | egrep "File|Position" | cut -d: -f2
```

Comment: Thanks @@fedorqui   i got these "log-bin.000055,120614936" actually these are dynamic it will change every one hour in dd.txt file.now  how can i update in my table using this query update db.position set binlog_file='log-bin.000055',position='120614936' where master_host='master.tb.com'; in mysql

Comment: Let's try with this: _$file = `cat dd.txt | egrep "File|Position" | cut -d: -f2`; $position = `cat dd.txt | egrep "File|Position" | cut -d: -f2`_.
Then you can use $file and $position in your query: `update db.position set binlog_file=$file,position=$position where master_host='master.tb.com'`

Comment: thanks @@fedroqui i want one more help i have a file like this [roome@server ~]# cat file -- CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000025', MASTER_LOG_POS=107; now i want only mysql-bin.000025,107 from the file how can i do this

Comment: @mithunakous, I cannot see how the file is clearly. Try to use `grep` as I posted before, cutting it with `cut -d:` (or `cut -d=` in this case), and getting rid of the '' by using `sed "s/'//g"`.
Post a new question otherwise.